# How to color a specific reference in Elsevier latex template

Tags: bibliographies, color, elsarticle

I would like to color a specific reference in the bibliography list in Elsevier latex template.

Any help would be so much appreciated.
Many thanks!

Comment: You could also edit the file .bbl created by BibTeX directly. This contains all the refs in the appropriate Elsevier template in LaTeX and editable. Just change the color of the part of the specific reference (authors, title, journal name, pages...) as you wish.

Comment: Thank you José! Could you please tell me what should I add in the .bbl file to color the references?

Answer (score 1):

I just found a solution. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{xcolor,etoolbox}

\let\mybibitem\bibitem
\renewcommand{\bibitem}[1]{%
\ifstrequal{#1}{Zhu2016}{\color{blue}\mybibitem{#1}}
{\ifstrequal{#1}{Zhu2017}{\color{blue}\mybibitem{#1}}
{\color{black}\mybibitem{#1}}}%
}
\begin{document}

For example these are new references \cite{Zhu2016, Zhu2017} and should 
appear in blue in the bibliography list. Other references should appear 
normally in black \cite{Sauer2003, Barrios2011}.

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
\bibliography{TwoPhaseFlow}
\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image: Output file for colored references in Elsarticle template]

You can simply color more references by modifying the following part in the previous code:

```
\let\mybibitem\bibitem
\renewcommand{\bibitem}[1]{%
\ifstrequal{#1}{Zhu2016}{\color{blue}\mybibitem{#1}}
{\ifstrequal{#1}{Zhu2017}{\color{blue}\mybibitem{#1}}
{\ifstrequal{#1}{Sauer2003}{\color{blue}\mybibitem{#1}}
{\color{black}\mybibitem{#1}}}}%
}
```

[image: Output file for colored references in Elsarticle template]

Answer (score 0):

We can do it in another way. Let us assume you have created the .bbl file with the references in the Elsevier format, such as:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{10}
\newcommand{\enquote}[1]{``#1''}

\bibitem{prudnikov}
A.~Prudnikov, Y.~Brychkov, and O.~Marichev, \enquote{Evaluation of integrals
and the mellin transform,} J. Sov. Math. \textbf{54}, 1239--1341 (1991).

... many others refs

\end{thebibliography}
```

This file can be put in the place of:

```
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
\bibliography{TwoPhaseFlow}
```

Now, you can edit the individual refs as you wish:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{10}
\newcommand{\enquote}[1]{``#1''}

\bibitem{prudnikov}
\textcolor{red}{A.~Prudnikov}, Y.~Brychkov, and O.~Marichev, \textcolor{green}{\enquote{Evaluation of integrals and the mellin transform,}}
\textcolor{blue}{J. Sov. Math.} \textbf{54}, 1239--1341 \textcolor{pink}{(1991)}.

... many others refs

\end{thebibliography}
```

You can obtain something like this for the reference edited:

[image]

Comment: Well, it is not exactly for an Elsevier journal, but it works anyway. ;))